# Can Advanced Custom Fields be built into a custom wordpress theme i.e. fields can be determined immediately when a user installs the theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So say I create some custom fields which can be edited via the front page editor.

I save these changes and want users of my theme to be able to see all of the custom fields I have made as *soon as the theme is installed*

This way, i can create a theme with pre-defined custom fields all over the website so users who install the theme can edit the custom fields straight away.

Otherwise, all the work done via advanced custom fields is rather pointless as when the theme is packaged, the user won't have access to the database that stores the files. I hope what I am asking makes sense!

EDIT: If this is not possible at all then I would accept that as an answer. If it is not possible then I would need to export then import the database for the made custom fields to display on a client's machine after they install the theme correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally reasonable question, and something that ACF has thought about and [created a guide for](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-within-a-plugin-or-theme/). There are basically two parts to this guide, which I'll summarize below:

- The actual ACF plugin must be included with your theme, which you can do by either:

  - Bundling the actual ACF PHP code with your theme (the actual plugin files)
  - Or, provide a link to the [ACF plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) and prompt users to install the plugin as part of your theme readme.
- Including the specific custom fields that go with your theme - this is what your question is mostly asking about. Again, a few different ways to do this:

  - As a new feature of ACF, you can register custom fields with your theme by using JSON files instead of storing the configuration in the SQL database. This is what I personally use, since it is [crazy easy to configure](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/local-json/) (just create an acf-json folder in the root of your theme) and allows you to use version-control (like GIT) to track custom field changes.
  - If you prefer the old way, you can [register your custom fields in your theme's functions.php file.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/)

---

Some additional information I can provide:

#### What about the storage of ACF values, not the configuration?

There is only one "database" for a given Wordpress installation, and the way ACF stores values that users have entered for custom fields with a given post is in the "wp_postmeta" table, by association the value with the post ID, field label (changeable), and field ID (permanent).

This is actually beneficial to you as a theme developer, because it means that if a user does something like installs your theme, enters a bunch of custom field values, accidentally uninstalls your theme or switches to a different one, and then wants to re-enable it, no data is lost.

#### Ensuring ACF gets installed with your theme

If you choose not to bundle the ACF source with your theme, and instead prompt users to manually install the plugin through the plugin directory, you might want to put some checks into your theme to ensure they do so. You can use something like `if(!function_exists('the_field')){ /* Block use of your theme until installed */ }` in some strategic spots in your theme code to check if ACF is installed, and if it is not, handle that appropriately and prompt admin to install.

Comment: Excellent, I have used TGMPA to prompt users of the theme to install any required plugin instead and that JSON method sounds great. Many thanks